# Should I replace this tire?

Tags: tires, damage

[image][image]

I recently bought a set of new tires. A week later I had a nail stuck in my tire so went to a mechanic to get it patched. After the patch he told me I could still drive it if the Bubble does not get bigger within the next 1-2 days. Is this still safe to drive?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I see the chalk outline, I'm not seeing a bubble. Probably just the lighting? Dunno.

Comment: I guess it's not a crazy bubble but it does bulge out slightly. I'll try to take a better photo to add.

Comment: Sidewall bubbles eventually cause a blowout.

Comment: Did you purchase any sort of Road Hazard Protection with the tire? If so, claim on that and get a new tire.

Answer (score 2):

Given this looks like a very low profile tyre, and therefore likely to be on a performance car, I would suggest that you replace it. Any bulge on the sidewall is suspect...

This could fail and it is the safety of you and any passengers riding in the car - a tyre is cheap compared to the long term consequences.

Comment: +1 sidewall bulges are **bad things** and indicate a structural weakness in a part of the tire that undergoes significant stresses. I'd be replacing this ASAP. I also wouldn't be using that mechanic again!

Answer (score -1):

well yea, i mean as lone as he did it well your good to go. one way he could have done it to prevent further leaks is by infusing a tube in to the tire. that way the tube gets inflated when pumped with the outer acting as a protective patch. at least that's what i would have done.

Comment: Inserting a tube into a tubeless tire is a bad idea (amongst other things the inside surface of tubeless tires are not generally smooth and this can chafe a tube to the point of failure) and is definitely **NOT** recommended for [repairing them](http://btmauk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Minor-repairs-to-passenger-car-and-light-van-tyres.pdf).